# Struggling to Automate Instagram Posts - Captions Missing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, instagram

I'm facing a puzzling issue while automating Instagram posts via a Chrome extension. When I run my script, photos upload successfully and the post gets created, but the captions don't appear in the final post. Strangely, if I run the automation and then manually click the "Share" button, it works fine.

I also tried to simulate all kind of events on the button like move, mouseover, or adding coordinates to the click event but nothing.

How can Instagram's underlaying JavaScript know if the share button was clicked by hand?

```
//SHARE BUTTON FINAL CLICK (if used the final post will miss the captions)
// Function to simulate a mouse movement and click event within a button with random offsets based on button dimensions
function simulateMouseClick(submitButtonElement, offsetXPercentRange, offsetYPercentRange) {
  // Get the dimensions of the button element
  const buttonRect = buttonElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const buttonWidth = buttonRect.width;
  const buttonHeight = buttonRect.height;

  // Generate random offsets as percentages of button dimensions
  const offsetXPercent = getRandomInRange(offsetXPercentRange[0], offsetXPercentRange[1]);
  const offsetYPercent = getRandomInRange(offsetYPercentRange[0], offsetYPercentRange[1]);

  // Calculate the click coordinates within the button element
  const clickX = buttonRect.left + (buttonWidth * offsetXPercent / 100);
  const clickY = buttonRect.top + (buttonHeight * offsetYPercent / 100);

  // Create a mouse event for mousemove
  const mouseMoveEvent = new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: clickX,
    clientY: clickY
  });

  // Create a mouse event for mouseover
  const mouseOverEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: clickX,
    clientY: clickY
  });

  // Dispatch the mousemove and mouseover events
  buttonElement.dispatchEvent(mouseMoveEvent);
  buttonElement.dispatchEvent(mouseOverEvent);

  // Create a click event
  const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: clickX,
    clientY: clickY
  });

  // Dispatch the click event
  buttonElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
```

I've tried various solutions, including instagrapi, but none offer carousel capabilities. I'm stumped and would appreciate any insights or suggestions. The official graph API seems to support it but I keep running into permission issues that I cannot request as I don't have a business.

Thanks for your help!